# AccuWork/Accurev adding attachments using command line

Tags: accurev

Does anybody know a way to add attachments/files to AccuWork/Accurev issue using command line?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a manual to AccuWork CLI.

http://www.accurev.com/download/docs/5.5.0d_books/AccuRev_WebHelp/AccuRev_User_CLI/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=cli&file=cli_accuwork.html

Basically you use 'accurev xml' command with XML API to create/edit issues. This is what the GUI will do internally. It makes it easier for you by creating a temporary xml files every time it calls this command, so just use some utility that captures all files on delete and use the GUI to do whatever, then read those xml files to figure out how to.